# How to pass filtered data from algolia to collection view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, algolia, instantsearch

Here I had filtered the data using `facetfilters` from given `facets` and got data in search query function and the response has been passed to model class shown below and in collection view delegate `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, containing hit: [String : Any]) -> UICollectionViewCell` hit data which was retrieving was default indices data and filtered data has not got in hit can anyone help me how to pass this data to collection view in swift 3 ?

Below here is my code which already tried

```
if (self.appId != nil && self.apiKEY != nil && self.Indices != nil) {
        InstantSearch.shared.configure(appID: "\(self.appId!)", apiKey: "\(self.apiKEY!)", index: "\(self.Indices!)en_products")
        InstantSearch.shared.params.attributesToRetrieve = ["*"]
        InstantSearch.shared.registerAllWidgets(in: self.view)
        if receivedText != nil {
            print(String(describing: receivedText!))
            InstantSearch.shared.searchBar(searchBar, textDidChange: receivedText!)
            InstantSearch.shared.params.attributesToRetrieve = ["*"]
            InstantSearch.shared.registerAllWidgets(in: self.view)
        }else {
            let query = Query()
            query.facets = facetsArray
            print(categoriesArray)
            query.facetFilters = categoriesArray
            query.hitsPerPage = 100
            InstantSearch.shared.searcher.index.search(query, requestOptions: nil, completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                self.lastResults = SearchHits(fromDictionary: data!)
                print(data)
                self.listCollectionView.reloadHits()
            })
        }
        hitsCollectionViews = [self.listCollectionView]
        ActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
open override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                  cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath,
                                  containing hit: [String : Any]) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //        print(hit)
    let cell: listItemCollectionViewCell
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hitCell", for: indexPath) as! listItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.listItemLabel.text = hit["name"] as? String
    cell.listItemPrice.text = hit["price"] as? String
    if let strImage = hit["image_url"] as? String {
        let baseUrl = "http:\(strImage)"
        cell.listItemImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.listItemImg.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        if URL(string: baseUrl) != nil {
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: baseUrl)!, cacheKey: baseUrl)
            cell.listItemImg.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else{
            cell.listItemImg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder")
        }
    }
    cell.wishListButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saleTappedButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.listItemStarRating.starBorderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.listItemStarRating.starBorderWidth = 0.5
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: What is `receivedText` and where is it coming from ?

Comment: that is my search bar text to filter the data @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: no i didn't get any error

Comment: all was fine now after making search from facetfilters i got the data in the query function which was required response that i need to pass to hit to display in collection view that's it but in hit i was getting `_en_products` data which was default whole data from this indices not filtered data @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: Is it possible to pass the filtered data using facetfilters to hit or not ? @RobertD.Mogos

Comment: Hi @VamsiS, Are you asking how to access the filters inside the collectionView delegate method, or are you having problems getting the filters to work?

Comment: I had passed the selected category id's and got response in selected function shown below `InstantSearch.shared.searcher.index.search(query, requestOptions: nil, completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                self.lastResults = SearchHits(fromDictionary: data!)
                print(data)
                self.listCollectionView.reloadHits()
            })` but how to pass the `data` in the above function to hit because in hit i am getting default indices data @GuyDaher